# Recognize USSD code in textview in Android

Tags: android, textview, ussd

There is an Activity that I want to set **autoLink** attribute of *TextView*. Also I want to recognize **USSD codes** like ***140*7#** and act when has touched it such as phone number, website url, email address.

[Notice] In general, I would like using a customize *TextView* that can recognize USSD codes, too.

[image]

I have been googling but I could not find a suitable solution.

Comment: Maybe you can create a Regex for the USSD code and match it with the text of the `TextView`

Comment: When I can match an USSD code in textview, what should I do? I want show it like phone number with blue color.

Comment: you can check before the using the `setText()` method and set the PaintFlags to underline and make the color blue.. OR 
you can extend `TextView` and override `onDraw()` method and check there

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. I should check it.

Comment: Hi omid, i want some information about ussd, connecting to that, sending data and anything like that, can you help me?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan check below answer, If it doesn't solve your problem. make a new question Or send an email to me.

Comment: omid i understand your code, but my problem is the reading data from `ussd`, example: when you call *140*1# `ussd` code going to run, then one dialog shows to you, like your credit, how can read that data? thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Last, I can find a solution for my request. As @basant_matharu mentioned at the comment, I extent TextView element that you can see that in below code:

```
public class LinkEnabledTextView extends TextView {


    // Pattern for gathering *140*1# from the Text
    Pattern ussdPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\*[0-9]+[\\*[0-9]+]*#)");
    private TextLinkClickListener mListener;
    private ArrayList<Hyperlink> listOfLinks;

    public LinkEnabledTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        listOfLinks = new ArrayList<Hyperlink>();

    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        SpannableString linkableText = new SpannableString(text);

        gatherLinks(listOfLinks, linkableText, ussdPattern);

        for (Hyperlink linkSpec : listOfLinks) {
            // this process here makes the Clickable Links from the text
            linkableText.setSpan(linkSpec.span, linkSpec.start, linkSpec.end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        // sets the text for the TextView with enabled links
        super.setText(linkableText);
    }

    public void setOnTextLinkClickListener(TextLinkClickListener newListener) {
        mListener = newListener;
    }

    private void gatherLinks(ArrayList<Hyperlink> links, Spannable s, Pattern pattern) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()) {
            int start = m.start();
            int end = m.end();

            Hyperlink spec = new Hyperlink();
            spec.textSpan = s.subSequence(start, end);
            spec.span = new InternalURLSpan(spec.textSpan.toString());
            spec.start = start;
            spec.end = end;

            links.add(spec);
        }
    }

    public interface TextLinkClickListener {
        public void onTextLinkClick(View textView, String clickedString);
    }

    /**
     * Class for storing the information about the Link Location
     */
    public class InternalURLSpan extends ClickableSpan {
        private String clickedSpan;

        public InternalURLSpan(String clickedString) {
            clickedSpan = clickedString;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            mListener.onTextLinkClick(textView, clickedSpan);
        }
    }

    class Hyperlink {
        CharSequence textSpan;
        InternalURLSpan span;
        int start;
        int end;
    }
}
```

In this class overridden setText() method for recognize any patterns like *USSD codes*. Also There is an interface named **TextLinkClickListener** that help us to call recognizes *USSD code*:

```
public interface TextLinkClickListener {
    public void onTextLinkClick(View textView, String clickedString);
}
```

Use custom class instead of TextView:

```
<com.example.test.custom_textview.LinkEnabledTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:autoLink="all"/>
```

And In your activity(for example):

```
LinkEnabledTextView textView = (LinkEnabledTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
textView.setOnTextLinkClickListener(this);
textView.setText(text);
```

Everywhere you want to call USSD code, you should write below code and call *LinkEnabledTextView listener*:

```
public void onTextLinkClick(View textView, String clickedString) {
    String ussdCode = clickedString.substring(0, clickedString.indexOf("#")) + Uri.encode("#");
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
}
```

Oh, be aware write call permissiion in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```